Getting the command tag from PostgreSQL with QtSql
PostgreSQL returns a "command tag" on INSERT or UPDATE statements.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/protocol-message-formats.html#PROTOCOL-MESSAGE-FORMATS-COMMANDCOMPLETE
E. g. an INSERT might return INSERT 0 1 or an UPDATE might return "UPDATE 12".
I would like to know the number of actual affected rows after executing a statement. QtSql offers a method called numRowsAffected but is sparse on its documentation. It is not clear if this count is the count of the matching rows or of the rows that actually get inserted/updated.
Thus I want to simply use the command tag for that. Can I get the command tag when using QtSql?

During your tests, have you found a discrepancy between the command tag and numRowsAffected? If yes, for what query?

To retrieve the PostgreSQL command tag using QtSql, one has to use the QSqlQuery::lastQuery() method to fetch the executed SQL statement first and then parse the output command manually. This feature is lacking directly with QtSql to access PostgreSQL command tag. You can inject your SQL query with a RETURNING clause so that the affected-rows information becomes available as part of the result set, to be handled by QtSql.
QtSql does provide a method called numRowsAffected() in the QSqlQuery class, which is designed to return the number of rows affected by the last executed SQL statement. This typically aligns with what you would see in the command tag, such as the number of rows updated or inserted. To fetch the command tag directly from PostgreSQL, use the next SQL with a RETURNING clause. This, however, does not give you the actual command tag like 'INSERT 0 1' or 'UPDATE 12', but it will inform you how many rows were affected.
For an INSERT operation:
INSERT INTO your_table (column1, column2, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
RETURNING 'INSERT ' || COUNT(*) || ' ' || (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE condition);

For an UPDATE operation:
WITH updated AS (
    UPDATE your_table
    SET column1 = new_value1, column2 = new_value2, ...
    WHERE some_condition
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT 'UPDATE ' || COUNT(*) FROM updated;

For a DELETE operation:
WITH deleted AS (
    DELETE FROM your_table
    WHERE some_condition
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT 'DELETE ' || COUNT(*) FROM deleted;

To get the command tag from a PostgreSQL query using QtSql,
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2) VALUES (:value1, :value2) RETURNING *;");
query.bindValue(":value1", value1);
query.bindValue(":value2", value2);

if(query.exec()) {
    // Process the result set to get the command tag
    while (query.next()) {
        QString result = query.value(0).toString(); // Process result
        qDebug() << "Command Result: " << result;
    }
} else {
    qDebug() << "Error: " << query.lastError().text();
}


So you are saying it is not possible to get the actual command tag with QtSql, correct? Do you have a reference for that?

Your workaround with RETURNING sounds interesting, does it count the actually inserted/updated/deleted rows correctly when Row Level Security is involved? The plain count from a query condition will not be the correct measure when RLS prevents certain rows from being access/changed.

As per qtsql documentation, you can get affected row count with numRowsAffected(), but could not find anything related to command tag
